# Spring boot App engine React doesnt map path

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, google-app-engine, react-router

im using spring boot java in the server and a web app built on react.
For some reason that i cant' seem to figure, i cant access my react components via url.
Like: https://myapp.appspot.com/profile gives me a  404 error. Is there a reason for this?
Because of app engine i configuree the servlet with code i found online. all works for the regular path ("/") but when i try "/profile" says it doesnt exist even tho it does. In react localhost it works perfectly.

Setup

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { JacksonAutoConfiguration.class })
@EnableScheduling
public class Backend {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Backend.class, args);
    }

    public static class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
        @Override
        protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
            return application.sources(Backend.class);
        }
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/../index.html</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

app-engine.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app
    xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">

    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <runtime>java8</runtime>
    <sessions-enabled>false</sessions-enabled>
    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file"
            value="WEB-INF/logging.properties" />
    </system-properties>
    <static-files>
        <include path="/**.html" />
        <include path="/**.png" />
        <include path="/**.ico" />
        <include path="/**.txt" />
        <include path="/**.json" />
        <include path="/**.js" />
        <include path="/**.svg" />
        <include path="/**.jpg" />
        <include path="/**.map" />
        <include path="/**.css" />
    </static-files>
    <resource-files>
        <include path="/**.html" />
        <include path="/**.png" />
        <include path="/**.ico" />
        <include path="/**.txt" />
        <include path="/**.json" />
        <include path="/**.js" />
        <include path="/**.svg" />
        <include path="/**.jpg" />
        <include path="/**.map" />
        <include path="/**.css" />
    </resource-files>
    <automatic-scaling>
        <target-cpu-utilization>0.9</target-cpu-utilization>
        <max-instances>30</max-instances>
        <min-instances>1</min-instances>
        <max-concurrent-requests>15</max-concurrent-requests>
        <max-idle-instances>2</max-idle-instances>
    </automatic-scaling>
</appengine-web-app>
```

Comment: can you share the code that you found and your app.yaml file?

Comment: I only have a app-engine.xml and a web.xml

Comment: @please, post these files

Comment: the code i found is the first one

Comment: I feel little bit confused, you can get all static resources from the path "/" but you can't get the static resources of the path "/profile", in this is the case maybe you need to map the full folder of the static files, instead to use a wide pattern 

```<include path="/profile" >```

Comment: Thats not a static file. It is a path within react router

Comment: I found a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43751258/how-to-use-reacts-browserrouter-on-client-and-java-rest-api-spring-boot-on-th